# What's wrong with this code for the Palindrome Problem in LeetCode?

Tags: python

I am working on the Palindrome Number problem on LeetCode. The instructions are as followed:

"Given an integer x, return true if x is a palindrome, and false otherwise."

I used the following code to change the integer to a string and reverse the string.

class Solution(object):

```
def isPalindrome(self, x):
    """
    :type x: int
    :rtype: bool
    """
    
    num = str(x)
    rev = ""

    for i in num:
        rev = i + rev
        
    return rev
```

The input x = 121 is fine but x = -121 and x = 10 come back as true when they should come back as false. When I just use print with this code, I get 121- and 01, respectively. However, LeetCode says it's wrong. I'm confused as to why.

If someone could give me a little more insight into the error, I'd appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: You're supposed to return a bool, but you're returning a string…!?

Comment: Btw, the reason it isn't failing the first test, is because, in python the truthiness of a string is `True` if it isn't an empty string

Comment: Ahh, I was assuming LeetCode was converting it to Boolean because I was getting true and false. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, the obvious solution in Python would be the one-liner `return str(x) == str(x)[::-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

"Given an integer x, return true if x is a palindrome, and false otherwise."

you are just returning a reversed string.

change that to:

`return rev == num`